# Show V is a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm looking for advice on this problem not an answer. How would I go about this.

Comment: Do you know how to do the problem if it were instead asking for the subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ such that $V=\left\{A=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}~:~a=b~\text{and}~c+2d=0]\right\}$?

Comment: Start by applying the definition of subspace.

Comment: Given the time of year, we aren’t about to help you on a take home final exam, are we? A little bit of context would nice to see.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** A matrix $A\in V$ is of the form

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&a\\-2d&d\end{pmatrix}$$

Can you check all the requirements for a vector space now?

**Hint 2:** How many numbers do you need in order to specify $A$ uniquely?